# Setting an environment variable with delayed expansion enabled

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script that should set an environment variable `%NUMBER%`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET processed=0

IF "%~1"=="latest" (
    CALL :LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER %~2
    ECHO "->%build_number% RETURNS NO DATA"
    ECHO "->!build_number! GIVES THE BUILD NUMBER BACK"
    CALL :SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE  !build_number!
    SET processed=1
)

:END
    ENDLOCAL
    ECHO ON
    @EXIT /B 0

:SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
    ECHO SET "NUMBER=%~1"
    SET "NUMBER=%~1"
    @EXIT /B 0

:LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER
    REM CALCULATE THE BUILDNUMBER, NOW JUST SET IT
    set build_number=589
    EXIT /B 0
```

When I do run this code in a command prompt window, and do an echo of the `NUMBER` variable, it is not set in console window.

```
d:\> ECHO %NUMBER%
%NUMBER%
```

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Each `setlocal` creates a new variable scope.
This scope will be destroyed with `endlocal` or implicit by exiting the batch file.

You have to safe your variables over the scope lifetime (often called `endlocal barrier`).

In a called function it's not possible to `ENDLOCAL` an outer `SETLOCAL` (not impossible, but only with [advanced technics](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6491)).
So you have to modify your code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET processed=0
SET build_number=0

IF "%~1"=="latest" (
    CALL :LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER %~2
    ECHO -^>%build_number% RETURNS NO DATA
    ECHO -^>!build_number! GIVES THE BUILD NUMBER BACK
    REM *** CALL :SET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE !build_number!
    SET processed=1
)

:END
(
  ENDLOCAL
  set "number=%build_number%"
  EXIT /B 0
)
...
```

The trick is to build an ENDLOCAL-Block with parenthesis, as the percent expansion is evaluated when the block is parsed, so the value will be available after the `ENDLOCAL` is executed.