# identify or delete double quote char in batch script text stream or in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, escaping, double-quotes

I have created command script for reading `%N%` lines from `file`. The problem is I can't delete `"` from anywhere in all text streams when I work with file's text. `"` deletion is very needed because if file's text line have substring like `"text"` and `text` have special chars or even worse, script code, then the script crashes or works not proper way (including script control capturing by programmer who specially composed the `text`).
If I can't delete `"` from the text stream(s), then I just want to identify, that the `file` (or it's first `%N%` lines, including empty lines) contains at least one `"` char.
Any thoughts are appreciated, including any `file` preprocessing. But main aim is script speed.

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('find /v /n "" "file" 2^>nul') do set "v=%%a"&call :v&if not errorlevel 1 goto FURTHER1
goto FURTHER2
:v
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ("%v%") do set "line%%a=%v:*]=%"&if %%a lss %N% (exit /b 1) else exit /b 0
```

Comment: Use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`!v!`) to avoid trouble with special characters; the problem is caused by the normal (immediate) expandion of variable `%v%`...

Comment: @aschipfl I need same variable scope at the script end, so elaborate, please, how to use delayed expansion in this case, because `setlocal` creates new scope and `endlocal` deletes the created scope

Comment: @aschipfl Even more: even with delayed expansion how to pass file's text line to variable? Anyway, the line appears before interpreter preprocessor. Or you have other solution?

Comment: If someone suggests the solution without `findstr`, it will be very good.

Comment: There are ways to pass variable vaues beyond the `endlocal` barrier -- see [Setting an environment variable with delayed expansion enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34153256), for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only identify `"`, but not delete. Waiting for your suggestions on it!

```
>nul 2>&1 findstr /m \" "file"
if not errorlevel 1 echo double quote found!
```

Comment: I'd just like to comment that Windows 'batch files' cannot edit/delete from the text stream and directly replace without using a third party tool or grabbing the services of another programming language. All you can effectively do is to write to another file and then replace the original file with the newly written one.

Comment: @Compo And what do you mean by 'to write to another file'?

Comment: What i mean is you cannot read the text stream, change it and write back to the source directly. You have to read, change, write to other then replace source with other. I hope that is clear enough for you.

Comment: @Compo I have understood first part of your first comment clearly, and no need to clarify it again. But I just thought that you mean more specific operation with file(s) and asked for it's clarification.

Comment: To delete, would it not be possible for you to create a variable containing the content of each line and write those variables to a new file by substituting doublequote for nothing, `ECHO %VARIABLE:"=%`?

Comment: @Compo Main barrier is inability to put text line from `file` to variable, though.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed that you'd tried to do that!

Comment: @Compo Are you kidding?

Comment: Of course I'm not, could you please direct me to the code which is failing to save lines into variables and then manipulating those variables through the method I have mentioned.

Comment: @Compo Of course, it's my starting post code! It is one of main reasons I have created the whole question! Because this code can't read ANY text. The limitation is `"` absence. Or you have method(s) to overcome this limitation? I'll be very glad to read it from you! One of other reasons of questionmake is inability to replace `"` directly in the `file`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read that code, you are taking each line then keeping everything after the first closing square bracket as a variable with linei

Comment: I use `find` because `for` can't read empty lines and for variable numbering, so firstly I add `[<number>]` with `find` to all lines, including empty, then I remove previously added `[<number>]` and use `<number>` to number destination variables.

Comment: Because you have already marked your question as answered, I'd suggest you create a new question where this time you also provide the input file and expected output file. I cannot understand why a line with a doublequote cannot be set to variable. I would therefore be grateful if you could better explain your need to delete those doublequotes midstream.

Comment: I can remark answer at any time, if more suitable one appears. Example of the text, that can't be read by the script: `"&exit&"` or `"&executable.exe&"`. Man, who can compose the text in the `file` can compromise the script.

Comment: There are far too many comments here. Please explain what your task is. A variable can be set containing double quotes and ampersands. What are you inputting? what are you outputting? what are you doing with the data captured? is something being manipulated? or are you just transferring n lines to a new file?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q39558311.txt"
SET "tempfilename1=%sourcedir%\q39558311#.txt"
>"%tempfilename1%" ECHO("
SET /a linefound=0
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /g:"%tempfilename1%" "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF %%a gtr 2 SET /a linefound=%%a&GOTO report
)
:report
ECHO quote found AT line %linefound%
DEL "%tempfilename1%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

`tempfile1` can be any name - it's just a temporary file; I chose that particular name for convenience.

I used a file named `q39558311.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Essentially, create a file containing a single quote on a single line *tempfile1) then use `findstr` with the `/g:filename` option to read in the target strings to find. When `findstr` finds the line, it numbers it and outputs `line_number:line found`. Using `:` as a delimiter, token 1 of this line is the line number.

I don't understand why you've used the `skip=number` in your code. Do you intend to skip testing the first 2 lines of the target file?

the `IF %%a gtr 2` tests the line number found. If it is greater than 2, then the variable `linefound` is set and the `for` loop is terminated.

I chose to initialise `linefound` to zero. It will remain zero if no `"` is found in lines 2..end. Equally, you could clear it and then it will be defined (with a value of first-line-found-with-quote-greater than-2) and no defined on not found.

Comment: `skip=2` is necessary because `find` prints 2 nondata lines before file data output, test `find /v "" "AnyFile"`, and you'll see

Comment: Your help is just suggesting `findstr` for reading `"` from other file. Thanks, I'll use it and post answer here.